# Programmatically stopping MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, electron

I am working on an application using Node.JS, Electron. This application will run its own instance of MongoDB. The start up of Mongo is working using the following code:

```
child = childProcess.exec(`mongod --dbpath ${appConfig.dbConfigPath}`);
```

However, when the user exits the program, I want to stop mongo. I have tried the following, all taken from [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/)

```
child = childProcess.exec('mongod --shutdown');
```

and

```
child = childProcess.exec(`kill -2 ${child.pid}`);
```

yet neither of these are shutting down the process.

This application is being developed to run on the windows platform.

For clarity, here is my app configuration file. The init() function is executed from within my main.js. The shutdown() is executed in the windowMain.on('close').

calibration.js

```
'use strict';

const childProcess = require('child_process');

const fileUtils = require('./lib/utils/fileUtils');
const appConfig = require('./config/appConfig');

let child;

class Calibration {
    constructor() {}

    init() {
        createAppConfigDir();
        createAppDataDir();
        startMongo();
    }

    shutdown() {
        shutdownMongo();
    }
}

function createAppConfigDir() {
    fileUtils.createDirSync(appConfig.appConfigDir);
}

function createAppDataDir() {
    fileUtils.createDirSync(appConfig.dbConfigPath);
}

function startMongo() {
    child = childProcess.exec(`mongod --dbpath ${appConfig.dbConfigPath}`);
    console.log(child.pid);
}

function shutdownMongo() {
    console.log('inside shutdownMongo');
    //This is where I want to shutdown Mongo
}

module.exports = new Calibration();
```

main.js

```
'use strict'

const { app, BrowserWindow, crashReporter, ipcMain: ipc } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

const appCalibration = require('../calibration');

appCalibration.init();

const appConfig = require('../config/appConfig');

let mainWindow = null;

ipc.on('set-title', (event, title) => {
    mainWindow.setTitle(title || appconfig.name);
})

ipc.on('quit', () => {
    app.quit();
})

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
app.on('ready', function() {

    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ center: true });

    mainWindow.maximize();

    mainWindow.setMinimumSize(770, 400);

    mainWindow.loadURL(path.join(`file://${__dirname}`, '../ui/index.html'));

    mainWindow.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Inside quit')
        appCalibration.shutdown();
        app.quit();
    });

    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
});
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use ipc to send an order and shut down your mongodb

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval, Thank you for the comment. Please forgive my ignorance, as I am just starting to understand Electron. Would you be so kind as to post an example? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Ipc` to send orders through your js files.

In your `main.js` where you defined your electron, you can put this:

```
ipcMain.on("shutDownDatabase", function (event, content) {
    // shutdown operations.
});
```

Then in some part of your application code, you can put a function like this:

```
function sendShutdownOrder (content){
   var ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
   // the content can be a parameter or whatever you want that should be required for the operation.
   ipcRenderer.send("shutDownDatabase", content);
}
```

Also I think you can use the events of Electron to shut down your db, this listens to the events of your mainWindow created when you start electron

```
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        // here you command to shutdowm your data base.
        mainWindow = null;
    });
```

For more information about IPC you can see [here](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/#ipcmain) and information about the events of your window [here](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#instance-events).

Answer (score 1):

With Paulo Galdo Sandoval's suggestion, I was able to get this to work. However, I needed to get the PID for mongod from Windows Task manager. To do that I added the following function to the application configuration js file

```
function getTaskList() {
    let pgm = 'mongod';

    exec('tasklist', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        var lines = stdout.toString().split('\n');
        var results = new Array();
        lines.forEach(function(line) {
            var parts = line.split('=');
            parts.forEach(function(items) {
                if (items.toString().indexOf(pgm) > -1) {
                    taskList.push(items.toString().replace(/\s+/g, '|').split('|')[1])
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I also declared an array variable to place the located PID in. Then I updated my shutdown function

```
function shutdownMongo() {
    var pgm = 'mongod';

    console.log('inside shutdownMongo');

    taskList.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log('Killing process ' + item);
        process.kill(item);
    });
}
```

With this I am now able to start and stop Mongo as my application starts up and closes.

Thanks all

Comment: After killing the process, is you application able to store all the data in the mongodb because there may be some data in the cache which may be lost after killing the process.

Comment: @Rohit, I have since left this project and no longer work with MongoDB. But, I do believe all the data was persisted.